# Gulp-compass compressing sass not working

Tags: css, sass, gulp, compass-sass

Running **Sass 3.4.3**, **Compass 1.0.1**, **Gulp 3.8.8** and **Gulp-compass 1.3.1**

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    gulp.src('comp/sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            sass: 'comp/sass',
            image: 'dev/theme/images',
            style: 'compressed'
        })
        .on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/theme/css'))
});
```

The Compass task is compiling the sass but compression is not working. It outputs a normal uncompressed CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the following:

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    gulp.src(sassSources)
     .pipe(compass({
        sass: 'components/sass',
        image: outputDir + '/images',
        style: sassStyle
     }))
     .on('error', gutil.log)
     .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + '/css'))
     .pipe(connect.reload())
});
```

Note that there is this variable sassStyle that is defined conditionally in this next portion of code where the node.js process.env process is 'watching' NODE_ENV value so we can switch between production folder and development folder:

```
env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
 if (env ==='development') {
    outputDir = 'builds/development/';
    sassStyle = 'expanded';
} else {
    outputDir = 'builds/production/';
    sassStyle ='compressed';
}
```

It didn't do the trick but an external config.rb file manually edited with:

```
config_file: 'config.rb',
```

with this line in the file worked:

```
output_style = :compressed
```

For now, I just left these lines commented out in the file as workaround.

I'm using the following devDependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
    "gulp-coffee": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-compass": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "mustache": "^2.2.1"
  }
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is from the Lynda.com web project workflows course. Where did you write `config_file: 'config.rb',`?

Answer (score 0):

What you've got should work, but I think the gulp-compass plugin is a bit buggy with the config properties. It works consistently for me with the output style in a separate config.rb file.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var compass = require('gulp-compass');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('compass', function() {
    return gulp.src('comp/sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            config_file: 'config.rb',
            sass: 'comp/sass',
            image: 'dev/theme/images'
        })
        .on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/theme/css'))
    ;
})
```

With this in the config.rb file:

```
output_style = :compressed
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I'm using sass 3.4.13 & gulp-compass 2.0.3.

Comment: I am having the same issue, and also tried the suggestion to use a ruby config file. It didn't work for me either.